# How does Redis work when RAM starts filling up?

Tags: caching, redis

I could be totally off, but my understanding of how *cache* stores used to work before they began to add persistence features, is that items would get expired based on their [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live). And if the store started to fill up available RAM, they would each have their algorithms for *expiring* the least "important" keys in the store.

Now I read that Redis has [*persistence*](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) features. But you can turn them off. Assuming you turn off persistence, what happen when RAM fills up? How does Redis decide what to expire?

I expect to have lots of data without TTLs and want to make sure it's safe to let Redis figure out what to expire.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't think the question is related to virtual memory management, but more about the expiration of the items in Redis, which is a totally different topic.

Contrary to memcached, Redis is not only a cache. So the user is supposed to choose about the item eviction policy using various mechanisms. You can evict all your items, or only a part of them.

The general policy should be selected in the configuration file with the maxmemory and maxmemory-policy parameters, decribed below:

```
# Don't use more memory than the specified amount of bytes.
# When the memory limit is reached Redis will try to remove keys with an
# EXPIRE set. It will try to start freeing keys that are going to expire
# in little time and preserve keys with a longer time to live.
# Redis will also try to remove objects from free lists if possible.
#
# If all this fails, Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
# that will use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
# to reply to most read-only commands like GET.
#
# WARNING: maxmemory can be a good idea mainly if you want to use Redis as a
# 'state' server or cache, not as a real DB. When Redis is used as a real
# database the memory usage will grow over the weeks, it will be obvious if
# it is going to use too much memory in the long run, and you'll have the time
# to upgrade. With maxmemory after the limit is reached you'll start to get
# errors for write operations, and this may even lead to DB inconsistency.
#
maxmemory <bytes>

# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached? You can select among five behavior:
#
# volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
# allkeys-lru -> remove any key accordingly to the LRU algorithm
# volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
# allkeys->random -> remove a random key, any key
# volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
#
# Note: with all the kind of policies, Redis will return an error on write
#       operations, when there are not suitable keys for eviction.
#
#       At the date of writing this commands are: set setnx setex append
#       incr decr rpush lpush rpushx lpushx linsert lset rpoplpush sadd
#       sinter sinterstore sunion sunionstore sdiff sdiffstore zadd zincrby
#       zunionstore zinterstore hset hsetnx hmset hincrby incrby decrby
#       getset mset msetnx exec sort
#
# The default is:
#
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru

# LRU and minimal TTL algorithms are not precise algorithms but approximated
# algorithms (in order to save memory), so you can select as well the sample
# size to check. For instance for default Redis will check three keys and
# pick the one that was used less recently, you can change the sample size
# using the following configuration directive.
#
maxmemory-samples 3
```

Then individual item expiration can be set using the following commands:
[EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire)
[EXPIREAT](http://redis.io/commands/expireat)
The per item expiration property is useful with volatile-* policies.
Expiration can also be removed using [PERSIST](http://redis.io/commands/persist).

The expiration property adds a slight memory overhead, so it should be used only if required.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that a part of an object cannot be expired, only the whole object itself. For instance, a whole list or set corresponding to a key can be expired, but individual list or set items cannot.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. So the defaul LRU algorithm is exactly what I wanted. Just need to set it so that it's a 'state' server.

Comment: This is wrong as of 2019. Navigate to http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf and you will see that the default policy is maxmemory-policy noeviction

Comment: The default is [noeviction](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/redis.conf)

Answer (score 9):

Didier is right in indicating how this is to be done. Just indicating some additional elements (one of which seems to be omitted from his post):

1. Specify the *max memory size* to take up most of the available memory
   on that node (leave some for the OS and other processes and some
   buffer). This will make sure that the content is never paged and as
   such the operations are FAST.
2. If you are not setting TTLs / expiring keys through the application,
   then it is important that you use the "*allkeys-lru*" approach.
   Otherwise, Redis will not expire anything (because none of the keys
   are volatile), and you'll start getting errors once all the memory
   get's used up - basically you'll not be able to do any more set
   operations.
3. When using the [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU)) for removing keys, it is important to set the
   following setting:

   ```
   maxmemory-samples 10
   ```

This is the number of samples that Redis will take and then remove the LRU key from amongst these. The *default* value is 3 but for all practical purposes this is too low - and may mean that older keys may still have survived. Setting this too high will be an overhead for Redis.
You may want to experiment with this setting a bit before setting it. We are using a value of 10.

Comment: You're totally right @Gur, I just tested it with different maxmemory and maxmemory-policy values.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [Virtual Memory](http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory) chapter from Redis documentation.
The relevant part:

> **The vm-max-memory setting**
> The vm-max-memory setting specifies how much memory Redis is free to use before starting swapping values on disk.
>
> Basically if this memory limit is not reached, no object will be swapped, Redis will work with all objects in memory as usual. Once this limit is hit however, enough objects are swapped out to return the memory into just under the limit.
>
> The swapped objects are primarily the ones with the highest "age" (that is, the number of seconds since they have not been used), but the "swappability" of an object is also proportional to the logarithm of it's size in memory. So although older objects are preferred, bigger objects are swapped out first when they are about the same age.
>
> *WARNING:* Because keys can't be swapped out, Redis will not be able to honor the vm-max-memory setting if the keys alone are using more space than the limit.
>
> The best value for this setting is enough RAM to hold the "working set" of data. In practical terms, just give Redis as much memory as you can, and swapping will work better.

**UPDATE**
As for Redis 2.4 (it seems like the official documentation in Redis site is not updated to that version), it's not recommended to use VM.

`redis.conf` says:

```
### WARNING! Virtual Memory is deprecated in Redis 2.4
### The use of Virtual Memory is strongly discouraged.
```

Comment: Since VIrtual Memory is deprecated, what is the best way to use on-disk memory when RAM memory limit hits?

Comment: @harsimranb Don't. If you get to the stage where you need the disk, you've misused Redis (or you should increase your RAM, depends on your use case).

Comment: @ofer-zelig what technology should be used instead?

Comment: @BrandonH.Gomes try other NoSQL databases like Cassandra, Mongo, HBase, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Either set TTLs (and let Redis handle the expiration for you) or post your items with your own aging data, perhaps stored as a ZSET of (timestamp,key) tuples from which you can perform your own cache cleaning according to your own needs.